# Classification Model

Tags: classification, categorical-data

I have different zones and they have different patterns of occupation, at the end i want to be able to predict the occupations of this zones.

So i have this information about the zones:

```
  Data            Hour  Day Occupation Zone 
  20/10/2017    20:20   Wed       10   1 
  20/10/2017    20:21   Wed       11   1
```

and so on for all the zones... with the total of the zone i can get the % of occupation for any time

The occupation of one zone could be influenced by the occupations of the others zones. I think its a classification problem because the occupatiion its going to be on labels for differente % of occupation.

Do you have something that i can read for the begining? 
Wich are the algorithms that i sould learn?

Comment: How many different labels are there for the occupation variable? Also, how many observations/data points do you have to play with? More information is needed before we can steer you in the right direction.

Comment: 3 labels. I don't know the % of each yet but it's going to be 3 labels.

I will have obeservations for each minute in one year, even when there are no occupation i will have data, with the lowest lable occupation,

Comment: No one can help me ?

Answer (score 1):

I still don't quite understand your project but I can direct you towards a couple of models to begin with. The first (and easiest) model is the decision tree. Decision trees on their own are very sensitive to noise but they're a great place to start. After decision trees, you can look into the random forest model. In simple terms, a random forest is a bunch of decision trees (with random partitioning/subspaces and other differences). You can't learn random forests without first conquering decision trees.

Another classification model to start with would be a basic, simple neural network. Learn that one in its simplest form and then you can expand beyond it to other neural networks.

I guess my point is that you should start with the most basic forms of any model and then work your way up. Without more information about what you're doing, this is the best I can offer. Hope it helps!

Comment: I tought decisisons trees to start too. So imagine that ocupation it's people departing and arriving a certain zone. At any minute i will have information about how many people are in that zone. And this ocupation its influenced by the day of the month, the hour and the day of the week. Are a "tutorial" for the algorithms i should test?

Comment: I'm sorry but your English is really rough. I don't understand what you're saying. "Are a "tutorial" for the algorithms I should test?"  Is this an assignment for school? If so, can you post the assignment?

Comment: I'm so sorry. I was tired when I wrote this.

What I mean is whether there is a list or algorithm guide that can be used in this situation.

Comment: That's alright. I am not aware of a "cheat sheet" or "algorithm guide" but I do know of a cheap book to help you get started. It doesn't go into too much detail (mathematically speaking) and it's a great starter book. In fact, I used it when I was just starting out. It's called "Discovering Knowledge in Data: An Introduction to Data Mining". It's published by the IEEE and Wiley Corp. Good luck to you